# Compile standalone .exe with resources

Tags: c#

I am trying to compile my C# program to a standalone .exe using csc but i somehow cannot include two .exes from the resources of that project. I need them in the final standalone.exe.
csc tells me that they are a binary instead of a text file (well duh). 
Any help would be appreciated ! :3

**EDIT:** Using /resource: I narrowed it down to this:

[image: http://puu.sh/38mMq.png]

Also if it is important:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using System.Diagnostics;

namespace WindowsFormsApplication1
{
public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        bool is64bit = !string.IsNullOrEmpty(
        Environment.GetEnvironmentVariable("PROCESSOR_ARCHITEW6432"));
        if (is64bit == true)
        {
            ProcessStartInfo startInfo = new ProcessStartInfo("devcon64.exe");
            startInfo.Arguments = "restart =display *";
            Process.Start(startInfo);
        }
        else
        {
            ProcessStartInfo startInfo = new ProcessStartInfo("devcon32.exe");
            startInfo.Arguments = "restart =display *";
            Process.Start(startInfo);
        }
    }
}
}
```

Comment: `csc.exe` only accepts source code as input.  See http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/yabyz3h4.aspx if you want to reference other .NET assemblies.

Comment: The command line you're using for `csc` would be appreciated. How in the world could we debug this question?

Comment: Are the other exes .NET assemblies?

Comment: Do you mean that you want the other executables copied into the output folder when you compile the project? If so, you need to change the project file. In VS you can do that by right clicking the file selecting properties. In the menu that opens there's a "Copy To Output Directory" option which you want to change from "Do Not Copy" to "Copy if Newer" or "Always Copy". You can also find this property in the csproj file if you open it in a text editor. The changes you make in the VS menu is just editing this for you.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you want these as embedded resources, you should be able to just use the `/resource` flag:

```
csc Foo.cs /resource:Bar.exe /resource:Baz.exe
```

If you want them as something other than embedded resources, you'll need to clarify what you're asking for.

Comment: @LeColonel: Well the compile-time issue is probably due to not referencing `System.Core.dll` - but to *execute* the other executable, you'll need to extract it at execution time. Is that really much better than just shipping all the executables together?

Comment: If i could just extract it to the Temp folder and delete it after the program quits, yes. I would only have to find out how to do it.

Comment: @LeColonel: Assembly.GetManifestResourceStream is your friend.

Answer (score 0):

> Not that I know of. You would have to include the other executable
>   separately.
>
> If the executable is self-contained, and has no dependencies that you
>   need to ship, then you could include the executable as a resource in
>   your main executable, then extract and save it to disk and execute it
>   when needed. It would still require some cross-process communication
>   to get the results, but you would have one executable you have to
>   ship.

[original answer](http://bytes.com/topic/c-sharp/answers/742394-how-include-executable-c-console-project)

p.s.
you can also read
[similar topic](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/forums/en-us/csharpgeneral/thread/466DF300-AA5D-4558-8FE1-38CF079E3803)